# Как изменить время подстветки клавиатуры на Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура, huawei

Как изменить время подсветки клавиатуры на Ubuntu? Использую Huawei MateBook X PRO. Есть ли какие-либо настройки? Допустим хочу сделать так,чтоб клавиатура светилась 10 минут вместо нынешних 15 секунд...

Comment: Попробуйте установить OpenRGB, вдруг в нём случайно есть поддержка (хотя никакой внятной информации об этом я не нашёл). Или потыкайте что-нибудь в районе этого https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Keyboard_backlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, универсального способа изменения подсветки клавиатуры в Ubuntu нет. Все решается на уровне firmware производителей. К слову, на ноутбуке **Huawei MateBook X Pro** изменить подсветку клавиатуры можно с помощью фирменной программы **Huawei PC Manager**(он доступен только в Windows, но изменения сохраняются и для других ОС).